# How do I make this pygame class and .self work

Tags: python

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))

x = 100
y = 100

class circle():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def draw(self, x, y):
        pygame.draw.circle(wn, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), 5)

circle.draw(x, y)
```

What am I missing? I am new to all of this and I am really confused. The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\davey\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Game\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    circle.draw(x, y)
TypeError: circle.draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What is going wrong with it?

Comment: You need to create an OBJECT of type circle.  As in `obj = circle()` / `obj.draw(x,y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call draw method first you want to create circle object [learn more here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

```
circ = circle(x, y)
```

Now you can call `circ` methods like `draw()` as `circ.draw(x, y)`

But let's look at draw method:

```
    def draw(self, x, y):
        pygame.draw.circle(wn, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), 5)
```

You are using `self` variables in `(self.x, self.y)` that means that arguments: x and y in `def draw(self, x, y):` are ignored because `self.x` refers to the one initalized here:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
```

So final code should look something like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))

x = 100
y = 100

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(wn, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), 5)

circle = Circle(x, y)
circle.draw()


# Workaround to keep window open. Exit by pressing ctrl+c in terminal
while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Notice I named `class Circle():` with uppercase C because that's [naming convention for python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names)

I advice to to learn about python classes from youtube or websites it will make more sense when to use `self` and what is difference between objects and classes etc.

Good luck in your programming journey!